# Does this ODE have an explicit solution? How can it be characterized?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider this ODE for $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$
$$
\frac{ d x}{d t} =
\pmatrix{\cos(t)  & -\sin(t)\\ \sin(t) &\cos(t)}
\pmatrix{0 & 0\\ 0 & -1}
\pmatrix{\cos(t)  &  \sin(t)\\ -\sin(t) &\cos(t)}
x
$$
Does it have an explicit solution? Which qualitative properties does it have?

Comment: For a start, the RHS is a product of four matrices, two of which are transposes of each other, each of whose columns are an orthonormal basis for the function space. This makes them orthogonal so you can write your equation as $Qx'=AQx$, though I'm not perfectly sure where this leads.

Comment: Mathematica cannot give an explicit solution.